# Error while allocating memory to a structure pointer

Tags: c, structure, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to allocate memory for my structure pointer which I am declaring globally. But I am getting this error --> `error: initializer element is not constant`

```
typedef struct A {
    uint32_t arr[30][4096];
    uint32_t var1;
    uint8_t  var2;
    bool     var3;
}B;

B *x = (B*)malloc(sizeof(B));
```

Can anyone explain me where I am doing it wrong. 
Also, instead than dynamic memory allocation, is there a direct way to allocate memory to structure pointers? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it the real code ? Because `member 1`in a structure doiesn't mean anything

Comment: Exactly the same code with `int a`, `int n` works, please, provide better information about types of members.

Comment: Please try to create [mcve] to show us, preferably something that we can copy-paste (without editing) and replicate the problem ourselves.

Comment: where does the error occur? are you including stdlib.h? Try changing `typedef struct A {` to `typedef struct {`

Comment: The edited code also works good for me... :/

Comment: This compiles, please show more code that's not where the error is.

Comment: @BobRun After this I am just using this pointer assign values to the structure first 2 members in one function and other 2 members in a different function. Then with those values I am doing some comparisons in a separate function. But the error is pointing to this line `B *x = (B*)malloc(sizeof(B));` . Also I forgot to mention, the structure is declared in a .h file and this structure pointer I am defining is in a .c file. I don't think that can be the cause of this error.

Comment: Are you doing `B *x = (B*)malloc(sizeof(B));` in the *global* scope, or inside a function? That should really be part of your [mcve].

Comment: By the way (but unrelated to your issue) in C you [should not cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have mentioned in my question that I am decalaring that structure pointer globally.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Even without the casting, still getting the same issue.

Comment: `B *x = (B*)malloc(sizeof(B));` : doing this in global scope is rather pointless anyway, just declare the variable as normal global: `B Foo;` and later at some point `B *x = &Foo;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `malloc` in global scope like declaring a variable.
You  must use constant to init a variable in global scope.

You can use it (it is a function call) inside a function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    uint32_t arr[30][4096];
    uint32_t var1;
    uint8_t  var2;
    bool     var3;
}A;

A *x;

int main()
{
    x = malloc(sizeof(A));

    if (x != NULL)
    {
        free(x);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Form the c99 standard.

> **6.7.8 Initialization**
>
> 4. All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has **static storage duration** shall be **constant expressions or string
>      literals**.

The constants are defined as follows:

> **6.4.4 Constants**
>
> Syntax
>
> constant:
>
> ```
> integer-constant       (e.g. 4, 42L)
> floating-constant      (e.g. 0.345, .7)
> enumeration-constant   (stuff in enums)
> character-constant     (e.g. 'c', '\0')
> ```

The standard defines constant expressions as follows:

> **6.6 Constant expressions**
>
> (7) More latitude is permitted for constant expressions in initializers. Such a constant expression shall be, or evaluate to, one
>   of the following:
>
> — an arithmetic constant expression,
>
> — a null pointer constant,
>
> — an address constant, or
>
> — an address constant for an object type plus or minus an integer constant expression.
>
> (8) An arithmetic constant expression shall have an arithmetic type and shall
>   **only have** operands that are integer constants, floating constants,
>   enumeration constants, character constants, and sizeof expressions.
>   Cast operators in an arithmetic constant expression shall only convert
>   arithmetic types to arithmetic types, except as part of an operand to
>   a sizeof operator whose result is an integer constant.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: I still have a doubt. If I declare the structure pointer globally like this `B *x;` and inside all the functions which will use this variable, I will allocate memory like this--> `x = malloc(sizeof(B));` , so should I have to do `free(x)` in all the functions ? I have to mention that these functions would be called iteratively multiple times.

Comment: Each time you allocate something with `malloc` you are consuming/allocating heap memory. If you don't `free` the allocated memory and overwrite the current value of the global variable `x` you are loosing the pointer to the allocated memory and that memory will be lost. So: always `free` the `m-allocated` memory before to `re malloc` new memory

Comment: Thanks for this information.

Comment: Alternatively you can use [realloc](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-66/) standard function

Comment: Ok will try out that too. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

C doesn't allow you to have generic statements or expressions in the global scope (outside of functions), not even for initializers. Only compile-time constants are allowed as initializers in the global scope.

If you want to initialize the pointer then you need to do it as an assignment inside a function, perhaps first thing in the `main` function:

```
// Definition of variable
B *x;

int main(void)
{
    // Initialization of variable through assignment
    x = malloc(sizeof *x);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.